# Удаление часть содержимого docx с помощью python

Tags: python, docx

Есть тысяча файлов docx с одинаковыми кусками текста, которые надо удалить. 
На данный момент нагуглил библиотеку для работы с docx файлами - python-docx

Следующий код выводит в консоль строки, которые мне надо удалить:

```
doc = docx.Document('folder/file.docx')
para = doc.paragraphs[:4]
```

То есть, первые 5 строк

И вопрос в том, как их, собственно, удалить.
replace через цикл не срабатывает

К тому же, по идее файлы не открыты на запись

Какие есть способы удалить эти строки? Может быть стоит копать в другую сторону

Comment: Вот решение https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/33#issuecomment-77661907

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за ссылку, но разобраться по этому примеру не смог, моя задача, как оказалось, решается довольно просто:

```
doc = docx.Document(path)
    para = doc.paragraphs[:4]
    for i in para:
        i.text = None
    doc.save(path + '.docx')
```